# Comparar conteúdo de uma Coluna

Tags: r, lista

Sou iniciante no R e precisava de ajuda para comparar conteúdo de colunas.

Primeiro ordenei minha tabela em função de uma coluna específica. Para isto usei a seguinte função:

```
 x = fread ("x.txt",sep=";")
 x_ordenado = x[order(x$V3),]
```

Estou trabalhando com arquivos que têm certa de 5 milhões de linhas, só que preciso reduzir este número. 
Um jeito seria eliminar os dados que são iguais a uma lista de 10450 itens. Isto é, nesses 5 milhões de linhas eu tenho uma coluna com valores iguais e diferentes ao desta lista.

Alguma ideia do que posso fazer?

obrigada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de mais de um jeito em R. A maneira mais simples seria utilizar o `%in%` para verificar quais dos seus valores não estão na lista de valores que você quer remover. Por exemplo:

```
> todos <- 1:10 #Seus dados, números de 1 a 10
> excluir <- c(2,3,5,7) #Valores que serão removidos
> todos[!todos %in% excluir] #Faz um subset dos valores não-contidos em excluir
[1]  1  4  6  8  9 10
```

Essa abordagem não me parece ser pesada mesmo para esta quantidade de dados, mas outra alternativa seria utlizar o `filter` do `dplyr`, que ficaria assim:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df <- data.frame(todos) #Transformando em dataframe
> df %>% filter(! todos %in% excluir)
  todos
1     1
2     4
3     6
4     8
5     9
6    10
```

Se você for aninhar outros comandos, o `dplyr` pode ser uma boa alternativa, caso contrário, não há necessidade de carregar o pacote apenas para isso.

Isso removeria seus valores indesejados, mas não acho que resultaria em uma melhora na manipulação dos dados, pois você removeria apenas 0,2% das linhas. Talvez seja possível melhorar o código em outros pontos para melhorar os passos que realmente são lentos, ao invés de reduzir o tamanho dos dados.

Comment: Obrigada por sua resposta!
Fiz dois teste com a primeira possibilidade, mas por algum motivo não funcionou. 
Tentativa 1
Fiz a leitura do meu arquivo que é uma tabela em uma variável. Depois a leitura da lista dos valores que desejo manter em outra variável. 

e então o comando ===  todos[!todos %in% excluir] mas não funcionou

Tentativa 2
Depois separei o arquivo em colunas, isto é, fiz a abordagem entre colunas, mas também não deu certo.
A segunda possibilidade resulta no seguinte erro: Error in UseMethod("filter_") : no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"

Comment: Você pode incluir na pergunta um exemplo do seus dados? O ideal é o resultado de `dput(head(x_ordenado))` e a mesma coisa pros valores da lista que você quer excluir. Sobre a segunda tentativa, você precisa instalar o pacote `dplyr`: `install.packages("dplyr")`.

Answer (score 1):

Criando um data.frame de exemplo :

```
dados <- data.frame(x = rnorm(30), y = c("a","b","c"))
```

Para excluir linhas você vai fazer uma operação lógica de conjuntos em que você vai selecionar os elementos que não estão no conjunto.

Vamos criar o vetor que tem as categorias de `y` que você quer retirar:

```
excluir <- c("a", "b")
```

Agora podemos selecionar apenas as linhas em que `y` não está no vetor `excluir` (o `!` serve para negar):

```
dados[!dados$y %in% excluir, ]
           x y
3   0.1003638 c
6   1.4888718 c
9   0.3561347 c
12 -0.4532080 c
15  0.3552320 c
18  0.6220573 c
21 -1.0136110 c
24 -0.4445456 c
27 -0.6974983 c
30  1.0516000 c
```

Como você está dizendo que sua base pode ser grande, além do `dplyr` que o Molx mencionou, outro pacote interessante é o `data.table`.  Com o `data.ble` ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
library(data.table)
dados <- data.table(dados)
dados[! y %in% excluir,]
             x y
 1:  0.1003638 c
 2:  1.4888718 c
 3:  0.3561347 c
 4: -0.4532080 c
 5:  0.3552320 c
 6:  0.6220573 c
 7: -1.0136110 c
 8: -0.4445456 c
 9: -0.6974983 c
10:  1.0516000 c
```